# Is it possible to restrict a group of users from all SharePoint Online sites except one?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, sharepoint-permissions, restricted-access

As the title says: "Is it possible to restrict a group of users from all SharePoint Online sites except one?".

I have a specific group of users that should be able to access one single site in our tenant but should not be able to access any of the other sites at all.

Is this possible, and how would such a scenario be set up?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Grant permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions) to these users on specific SharePoint site.
2. Remove their permissions on all other SharePoint sites.

**Additional reference**: [Add or delete users in Microsoft SharePoint Online](https://kb.iu.edu/d/azzn)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: For security reasons, a specific group of users should only have access to one specific site and not any other existing or future sites. This means if e.g. someone adds the group "Everyone except external users" the specific group should still not have access.

Comment: "Everyone except external users" is the built in group and it's not posssible to remove any users from this group.Consider using conditional access to prevent the specific group from sites.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/block-access-sharepoint